# How to select a row from grid view and edit the details in a new webform using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I have displayed some fields in grid view, Now i want to select a row and i want to display all field from sql server in to a web form, after displaying the data in respective controls(textbox, dropdown), i want to update it.

How i can redirect the page to new webpage after selecting the respective row from grid view (Using primary key). and how the data will be pass on page load in respective fields so i could able to update it by using update query.

As i  new to ASP. Net. Please update me in detail. If possible please with code.

Comment: Please don't add things like "(C#)" to your titles. That's what the tags are for. Also, you should prefer one of the general tags like [c#] over a version-specific tag like [c#-4.0] unless your question is specific to that version.

Answer (score 1):

It would go something like this.

1. You will make a **'list'** webform with all records containing the gridview
2. Make another webform called **details**
3. The gridview on list page will contain a hyperlink button field something like this

> ```
> <asp:HyperLinkField Text="View Details" DataNavigateUrlFields="YourId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="details.aspx?id={0}" />
> ```

(Notice I am just redirecting to the details page passing the field id with querystring.

1. Now, on details page you would just fetch the querystring value & query your database with a datareader & populate your details page.
   Something like on page load

> ```
>   if(Request.QueryString["id"])!=null) 
>   {
>       // Fetch respective item from database here & populate form fields  
>         // Open connection(); execute datareader;populate form fields
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" autogeneratedcolumn="false">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("ID")%>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("ID")%>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HaderText="Edit">
<ItemTemplate>
<a href='EditData.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID")%>'>Edit</a> 
</ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
<asp:GridView>
```

EditData.aspx page will be used to edit the data. After receiving the Query-string Value,we can bind the data to the controls and then update the data after making changes.